# What is a handle in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm learning to developing in Php and Wordpress. Somebody can explain to me what mean a handle in this context:

```
<?php wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $media ); ?>
```

> Parameters
>   $handle
>   (string) (required) Name used as a handle for the stylesheet. As a special case, if the string contains a '?' character, the preceding part of the string refers to the registered handle, and the succeeding part is appended to the URL as a query string.
>   Default: None

url: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Thanks!! :)

Comment: I think this is more a question for [Wordpress Development](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), anyway the handle is a sort of name or alias you register/give to that resource to identify it and be able to refer to it (like if some other style depends on it you can pass it as dependency).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a handle is just an identifier. In this case, the handle is just a unique name for the script you are enqueuing.

If you were using `wp_register_style`, you could use the handle to enqueue the registered style:

```
wp_register_style('style-id', get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to/style.css', array(), '1.0');
/* ... */
wp_enqueue_style('style-id');
```

You can also [dequeue styles](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style) using the handle as a way to reference the desired style.

The documentation you referenced pertains to a special case when using `wp_enqueue_script`. In this instance you can use the handle parameter to also specify a query string for your script:

```
wp_enqueue_style('style-handle?query=string', get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to/style.css', array(), '1.0');
```

In the above example, the handle is `style-handle`. The portion after the `?` will be added the the enqueued script as a query string.

Comment: Thanks a lot @mtinsley!! It was a very useful answer! Now I'm a better developer thanks to  you! ;) :)